# how to only move specific file types in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move only specific filetypes (*.txt,*.fehler for example) to another directory. I want to seperate the files by last modified date into seperate folders (by year). If the directory isn't there it should create that folder. The following code works, if I am not filtering for the file types. What do i need to do to filter correctly?
This is my code so far:

```
$path = "H:\Downloads\tmp\source\"
$targetDir = "H:\Downloads\tmp\dst\"
Foreach($file in  (Get-ChildItem $path -Include *.txt,*.fehler))
{
   $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year
   $pastePath = $targetDir + $year.ToString()
   if(-not (Test-Path $pastePath ) -and ($year.ToString().Length -eq 4))
   {
      md $pastePath
   }
   $source = $path + $file
   Move-Item $source $pastePath -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the filter isn't working but this works for me:

```
$path = "H:\Downloads\tmp\source\"
$targetDir = "H:\Downloads\tmp\dst\"
Foreach($file in  (Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.Extension -match ".txt" -or ".fehler" } ))
{
   $year = $file.LastWriteTime.Year
   $pastePath = $targetDir + $year.ToString()
   if(-not (Test-Path $pastePath ) -and ($year.ToString().Length -eq 4))
   {
        md $pastePath
   }
   $source = $path + $file
   Robocopy.exe $path $pastePath $file /MOV
   <#Move-Item $source $pastePath -Force -Verbose#>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your extentions in quotes,

Like this:

`Foreach($file in  (Get-ChildItem $path -include "*.txt","*.fehler"))`

Comment: tried that - doesn't work. No files were moved. Filenames look like this: 4564160518161059_20160520_132701.TXT

Comment: Also, trying 'ls -Filter "*.txt"' in the shell works just fine and gives me all files that i'm looking for even if the file ending is in capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely works, but only when appending a required asterisk on the path, as per our docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-get-child-items-using-the-include-parameter

```
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem -path "$TmpDirectory\Icons\*" -Include "*.ico","*.msc")) {Move-Item $file "C:\Windows\System32\"}
```